# Create in-memory optimized table type

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am trying to create User Defined Table Type with `MEMORY_OPTIMIZED` on SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition, but I am getting an exception:

> Msg 12332, Level 16, State 111, Line 1
>   Database and server triggers on DDL statements CREATE, ALTER and DROP are not
>  supported with memory optimized tables.

Here is my create statement:

```
CREATE TYPE TTranslation AS TABLE (
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    Lang NCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    Translation NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    INDEX IndxTranslation NONCLUSTERED (Id,Lang)
) WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON)
```

What is a solution for creating in-memory optimized table types?

Comment: Do you have a DDL trigger on your database?

Comment: Yep, problem is definitely that you already have a DDL trigger on the database like Dale mentioned. Have you also already created a memory-optimized filegroup and added a folder? (That's not your current problem but will be your next one if they don't already exist)

Comment: i dont have any trigger, its new created development database as like as testing purpose .

Comment: @ErsinTarhan The DDL trigger need not to be on Database its self. It can be defined in the server level too. Please check in the SQL server level. Because error points to the Trigger and Memory Optimized objects doesn't support DDL triggers